# Find all duplicate documents in a MongoDB collection between a date range

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a collection with some set of documents. something like this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002d"), "orderId" : "ABCD1234", "createdAt": ISODate("2019-10-10T17:30:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002e"), "orderId" : "XYZ1234", "createdAt": ISODate("2020-08-10T17:30:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002f"), "orderId" : "ABCD1234", "createdAt": ISODate("2020-11-10T17:30:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002a"), "orderId" : "ABCD1234", "createdAt": ISODate("2020-11-10T17:30:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002b"), "orderId" : "XYZ1234", "createdAt": ISODate("2020-11-10T17:30:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002c"), "orderId" : "PQRS1234", "createdAt": ISODate("2020-11-10T17:30:00.000Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200003d"), "orderId" : "HIJK1234", "createdAt": ISODate("2020-11-10T17:30:00.000Z") }
```

I want to find all the duplicated entries in this collection that have the same `orderId` after 1st November 2020.

I am unable to get an aggregate query working where it can find duplicate records on a set of data in a date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` `createdAt` date is greater than you input date
- `$group` by `orderId` and get first group's record from duplicate, get count of duplicate records
- `$match` if count is greater than 1 means duplicate records
- `$replaceRoot` to replace root object in root

```
// correct date if i am wrong
var date = new Date("2020-11-02T00:00:00.000Z");
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { createdAt: { $gte: date } }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$orderId",
      root: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MLkAS0vKQA8)